# autofocus for input field is not working?

Tags: html

I am using a Tab which have many sub-tabs. I want to apply HTML autofocus on each sub-tabs first input field.But its only working for first assigned autofocus on sub-tab remaining sub-tabs autofocus is not working. 
Code:
1st Sub-tab:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control dep-name" name="currency_code" id="currencycodeid" autofocus placeholder="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;">
```

2nd sub-tab:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pay-name" name="payment_name" id="paymentname" placeholder="" autofocus onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;">
```

3rd sub-tab:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ship-name" name="shipping_name" id="shippingname" autofocus placeholder="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;">
```

Now when I am applying autofocus for every sub-tab, only first sub-tab is working, when I am applying 2nd & 3rd sub-tab, its only working on 2nd sub-tab....

Comment: would you mind showing your html and css?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the default behaviour.The autofocus attribute specifies the element that should be focussed on page load. Here as page loads first tab will be focussed

Comment: ur application is working in the right way. Is there a need to focus different fields at a time?

Answer (score 1):

It is working based on your explanation. You only got the idea of `autofocus` wrong.

The `autofocus` attribute is a boolean attribute which lets you specify that a form control should have input focus when the page loads, unless the user overrides it, for example by typing in a different control. **Only one form element in a document can have the autofocus attribute**, which is a Boolean. It cannot be applied if the type attribute is set to hidden (that is, you cannot automatically set focus to a hidden control). Note that the focusing of the control may occur before the firing of the DOMContentLoaded event.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: Could you explain very well what you want to do.? when do you expect focus to occur?  because we already answered your question 'autofocus for input field is not working?' Yes, it is working. You are just understand and use it wrong. or perhaps you should not use autofocus in your case.